# How can Solaris sub-partitions be accessed in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, partition, solaris

First of all, Linux detects the partitions:

```
sdg1: <solaris: [s0] sdg5 [s1] sdg6 [s2] sdg7 [s8] sdg8 >
```

However, FreeBSD 9.0 shows only the main partition. Is it possible that only Solaris labels for sparc64 are supported?

Comment: Not sure about the FreeBSD but does FreeBSD has the capability of reading Solaris Disk Labels?  Linux does for sure.

Comment: @Karlson, isn't it the thing my question is all about? )

Comment: What's the value of `kern.features.geom_sunlabel`?

Comment: @Karlson — it depends on whether `geom_sunlabel` is loaded or not. It's 1 when it's loaded.

Comment: And is it loaded?

Comment: @Karlson, sure.

Comment: I've asked around and `kldload geom_part_vtoc8` should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to:

```
/boot/kernel
```

and loading:

```
kldload geom_sunlabel.ko
```

Check if labels showed up. If they didn't you're unlikely to be able to access them (easily)

Long time ago I made it work:

http://marc.info/?l=freebsd-bugs&m=110942523517592&w=4

But soon after that I removed Solaris and never came back to it.

FreeBSD disk infrastructure is based on GEOM subsystem. GEOM modules are kernel modules. They are made so that upon insertion of each module in the kernel, modules will 'taste' first several sectors of your disk. If they recognize the format, they'll attach to it and start serving convent. Sun's "labels" are basically separate partitioning scheme, that must be recognized by the OS.

If you still can't see it, you'll be either forced to find another solution, or do some kernel hackery.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32643/how-can-solaris-sub-partitions-be-accessed-in-freebsd/141657#comment44492_32643